# Make python file executable that depends on other own written modules

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

I'm doing a project in PyCharm with 3 different python file while File A imports file B and file B imports file C. It works fine in PyCharm but since I wanna execute File A in the console it throws ModuleNotFound errors (they are in the same directory).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D99qT.png)

And can anybody tell me why pymongo isn't found?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `pymongo` is not the name of any file in your directory, the reason you are getting the *ModuleNotFound* error is because the `pymongo` package is not available to the interpreter. In order to install the `pymongo` package, you need to install it using `pip`, the package manager for python.

You can install `pymongo` with the following command on 
**Windows**: `pip install pymgono` or if that doesn't work `python -m pip install pymongo` 
**Mac** `pip3 install pymgono` or if that doesn't work `python3 -m pip install pymongo`

Answer (score 0):

Being that the ModuleNotFound Error, the show's that `pymongo` isn't found; There are some steps to resolve this, i believe that you already installed `pymongo`, but by double checking, try on your command prompt `pip install pymongo`, if you already have it then, I would try `python -m pip install pymongo` within the terminal of the compiler your using if this still persists I do believe it should be a directory problem.
To see the path directory of where pymongo is you can `try pip show pymongo` this should tell you if the pymongo is intalled show you it's files and where it is at.
Further more  ,[here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.2/installation.html), This should help you with more and further information.

Comment: Following up with this, you could also try pip uninstall pymongo then pip install pymonog into a specific path

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what the problem has been.